# how to use angular js on web page transfer

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I an a new learner in angular js, I have read all basic tips on w3school, but now I do the login function, so when I click the "sign in" button, the web page need to transfer to login to the website, but I have no idea how to do this, all the knowledge I've learned are just small pieces of functions, how can I use angular to do a project, actually I have searched on website but there codes are too complex for me to learn.

Comment: you only used w3school as reference? AngularJS has their own documentation [https://docs.angularjs.org/guide]. You can read ngRoute.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use `ng-route` or `ui-router`,they both provide routing mechanism using which you can navigate from one page to another.

As you are quite new to angularjs i suggested you see the following basic demo of routing to understand it better : https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router